# Nest.js swagger module - object in dto not visible in swagger

Tags: swagger, nestjs

I'm implementing small app in nest js with swagger, i have one column (postgresql) as json object (simple json type in typeorm) and the nested object is not visible in swagger. My code for it:

```
@ApiModelProperty()
@IsOptional()
  readonly foo: {
  boo: string[];
  boo2: string;
  boo3: string;
  ..etc
 };
```

in swagger I have only foo visible with empty object, is it posible using swagger nest js module to make the whole json object visible?

thx in advance 
Karol

Comment: What version of NestJS is this question related to ? Also which version of NestJS/ Swagger  ?

Answer (score 2):

Use an explicit type

```
export interface Foo {
  boo: string[];
  boo2: string;
  boo3: string;
  ..etc
}
```

and

```
@ApiModelPropertyOptional({ type: Foo })
@IsOptional()
readonly foo: Foo;
```

Comment: What? Shouldn't answer a question with an answer? but then with what? Another question?

Answer (score 1):

Use a class instead

Example:

```
import { ApiProperty, ApiPropertyOptional } from '@nestjs/swagger';
import { IsArray, IsNotEmpty, IsString } from 'class-validator';
import { Type } from 'class-transformer';

export class StickerRequest {

    @IsNotEmpty()
    @IsString()
    @ApiProperty({ example: 'sticker 01' })
    readonly name: string;

    @ApiPropertyOptional({ example: 'This is sticker description' })
    readonly description?: string;

    @ApiPropertyOptional({ example: 'ami-01, ami-02' })
    readonly tags?: string;

}

export class CollectionRequest {

  @ApiProperty({ example: 'Ami' })
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsString()
  readonly collectionName: string;

  @ApiPropertyOptional({ example: 'This is collection description' })
  readonly description?: string;

  @ApiProperty({ example: 'fffa73e4efca9245489e2bac' })
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsString()
  readonly author: string;

  @ApiProperty({ type: StickerRequest }) <------- Here
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsArray()
  @Type(() => StickerRequest)
  stickers: StickerRequest[];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not create/use interface's create a subDto (use export or not if you want) e.g:

```
export class SubDto {
    @ApiModelProperty({ type: String })
    @IsString()
    readonly subStringOne: string;

    @ApiModelProperty({ type: String })
    @IsString()
    readonly subStrinTwo: string;
}

export class MainDto {

    @ApiModelProperty({ type: String })
    @IsString()
    readonly mainStringOne: string;

    @ApiModelProperty({ type: [SubDto] })
    @IsArray()
    readonly mainArray: SubDto[];

    // or do the same thing for objects
    @ApiModelProperty({ type: SubDto })
    @IsJSON() // @IsOject doesn't exist in Nestjs so I use @IsJSON().
    readonly mainObject: SubDto;
}
```

Comment: This was unnnecessary for me tbh. Swagger used/displayed things correctly without mentioning the type.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're using an older version of nestjs, since `@ApiModelProperty` is now called `@ApiProperty`.
I suggest you to upgrade nestjs and swagger to their latest versions and follow these steps, worked for me quite well:

https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/swagger#openapi-swagger

hope that helps.